# Is it possible to disable swipe keyboard in windows phone 8.1 RT TextBox

Tags: windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to disable swipe keyboard in TextBox just like PasswordBox does.

Comment: I have edited my answer with better explanation and pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround.

Add a textbox (and delete the text in it)
[image: Add a textbox (and delete the text in it)]
Add a passwordbox on The textbox
[image: Add a passwordbox on the textbox]
Set the passwordboxes opacity to 0%
[image: Set the passwordboxes opacity to 0%]
Make a passwordchanged trigger on The passwordbox (double click on passwordbox does the same) and write a code on that sets the text of The textbox to The passwordboxes password (add names to The passwordbox and textbox before this)
[image: Make a passwordchanged trigger on The passwordbox (double click on passwordbox does the same) and write a code that sets the text of The textbox to The passwordboxes password (add names to passwordbox and textbox before this)]
You must be done! 
I hope I helped you.

Comment: If this doesn't work, then put a invisible rectangle on textbox and under passwordbox. That should work.

Comment: Ps I wasn't able to test it. I'm on my Phone and I can't install builds without a pc. (even wrote the code on a cloud vm)

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily the best solution, but playing with the `InputScope` might get you what you want. For example, this won't allow the shape-writing keyboard:

```
<TextBox InputScope="NameOrPhoneNumber"/>
```

The list of possible `InputScope` values can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscopenamevalue.aspx).
[Edit: Updated for XAML]

Answer (score 0):

I Think it's impossible to disable swipe keyboard in textBox but you can disable it from phone settings (Settings -> Keyboard -> tap your keyboard language -> uncheck "Type as I swipe through letters").